# Ruby on Rails: trying to create a new object that belongs to a user... not sure how to do it... correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controllor:

```
  def new(user)
    @address = Address.new
    @address.user_id = user.id
  end
```

The link I click that triggers the error

```
<%= link_to "Add Address", new_address_path(current_user)%>
```

Address model

```
  belongs_to :user
```

User Model

```
  has_many :addresses
```

New Address View

```
<h1>New Address</h1>

<% form_for @address, :url => new_address_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :object => f %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Address" %>
<% end %>
```

Schema for Addresses

```
  create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "number"
    t.string  "street"
    t.string  "city"
    t.string  "state"
    t.string  "zip_code"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

my routes

```
  map.resources :users
  map.resources :addresses
```

And the error is

```
uninitialized constant AddressesController
Parameters:

{"format"=>"#<user:0x105498c60>"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what controller is this method placed:

```
 def new(user)
    @address = Address.new
    @address.user_id = user.id
 end
```

Comment: its in the address cornotreller

Comment: please make sure it is in the 'addresses' controller and not 'address' controller...

Comment: Glad to help you... :) I was able to quickly spot the problem since i'm just a Rails beginner and good with the basics.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new_address_path(current_user)
```

try using:

```
new_user_address_path(current_user)
```

and make sure current_user is a valid user object.

Comment: undefined method `new_user_address_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x105070868>